# Spring data + MongoDB: single index or compound index for best performance when results need to be sorted

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm implementing a service that finds messages by sender (`from`) and sorted by `timestamp`.

I have this `MessageService`:

```
  public List<Message> findByFromAndSortedByTimestamp(String from, Integer limit) {
    return messageRepository.findByFrom(from,
        PageRequest.of(0, limit, Sort.by("timestamp").descending()));
  }
```

And this `MessageRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageRepository
    extends MongoRepository<Messsage, String> {

  List<Message> findByFrom(String from, Pageable pageable);
```

My question is about indexes in MongoDB. For the fastest response in `findByFromAndSortedByTimestamp`, do I need to create an index only on `from` field or I need a compound index with `from` and `timestamp` fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compound - it should allow the index to provide the sort

Comment: I would like to have this response as an answer, but with some query plan showing that a compund index is the best choice, thanks!